# select first in and last out time - different date - from data finger

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, pivot

Here is my data finger table, [dbo].[tFPLog]

```
CardID  Date        Time   TransactionCode
100     2020-09-01  08:00  IN
100     2020-09-01  17:00  OUT 
100     2020-09-01  17:10  OUT 
200     2020-09-01  16:00  IN
200     2020-09-02  02:00  OUT
200     2020-09-02  02:15  OUT
100     2020-09-02  07:00  IN
100     2020-09-02  16:00  OUT
200     2020-09-02  09:55  IN
200     2020-09-02  10:00  IN
200     2020-09-02  21:00  OUT
```

Conditions

1. Assume Employees will be IN and OUT in same day/next day.
2. Assume There will be multiple IN and OUT for same day/next day for employees. So need **first IN and Last Out**.
3. Duration = (FirstInTime - LastOutTime)

---

The current result i get using the query:

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT CardID,
       [Date] AS DateIn,
       MIN(CASE TransactionCode WHEN 'In' THEN [time] ELSE '23:59:59.999' END) AS TimeIn, --'23:59:59.999' as we are after the MIN, and NULL is the lowest value
       [Date] AS DateOut,
       MAX(CASE TransactionCode WHEN 'Out' THEN [time] END) AS TimeOut
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CardID, [Date])
SELECT C.DateIn,
   C.TimeIn,
   C.DateOut,
   C.TimeOut,
   DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,C.TimeIn,C.TimeOut),CONVERT(time(0),'00:00:00')) AS Duration
FROM CTE C;
```

=====**The Current Result**======

```
CardID  DateIN      TimeIN  DateOUT     TimeOUT  Duration
100     2020-09-01  08:00   2020-09-01  17:10    09:10
200     2020-09-01  16:00   ?           ?        ?
100     2020-09-02  07:00   2020-09-02  16:00    09:00
200     2020-09-02  09:55   2020-09-02  21:00    11:05
```

=====**The Result Needed**=====
I want this result.

```
CardID  DateIN      TimeIN  DateOUT     TimeOUT  Duration
100     2020-09-01  08:00   2020-09-01  17:10    09:10
200     2020-09-01  16:00   2020-09-02  02:15    10:15
100     2020-09-02  07:00   2020-09-02  16:00    09:00
200     2020-09-02  09:55   2020-09-02  21:00    11:05
```

How to get the DateOUT and TimeOUT in the nextday? with the condition FIRST IN AND LAST OUT. Please help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like you were really overly complicating the problem. Just use some conditional aggregation, and then get the difference in minutes:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT CardID,
           [Date] AS DateIn,
           MIN(CASE TransactionCode WHEN 'In' THEN [time] ELSE '23:59:59.999' END) AS TimeIn, --'23:59:59.999' as we are after the MIN, and NULL is the lowest value
           [Date] AS DateOut,
           MAX(CASE TransactionCode WHEN 'Out' THEN [time] END) AS TimeOut
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY CardID, [Date])
SELECT C.DateIn,
       C.TimeIn,
       C.DateOut,
       C.TimeOut,
       DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,C.TimeIn,C.TimeOut),CONVERT(time(0),'00:00:00')) AS Duration
FROM CTE C;
```

This *assumes* that `[date]` is a `date` and `[time]` is a `time` (because, after all, that is what they are called...).

*Side Note: it seems some what redundant have a `DateIn` and `DateOut` column when they will always have the same value. Might as well just have a `[Date]` Column.*

---

Or perhaps, you are actually after this?

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT CardID,
           [Date] AS DateIn,
           [Time] AS TimeIn,
           LEAD([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY CardID ORDER BY [Date], [Time]) AS DateOut,
           LEAD([Time]) OVER (PARTITION BY CardID ORDER BY [Date], [Time]) AS TimeOut,
           TransactionCode
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT C.DateIn,
       C.TimeIn,
       C.DateOut,
       C.TimeOut
FROM CTE C
WHERE TransactionCode = 'IN';
```

Note that if that is the case, you would actually be better off storing the values `[date]` and `[time]` in a single column as a `datetime`/`datetime2`, not separate ones; as the values are clearly *not* distinct from each other.

---

Based on the (hopefully) final goal posts:

```sql
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(100,CONVERT(date,'20200901'),CONVERT(time(0),'08:00:00'),'IN'),
                (100,CONVERT(date,'20200901'),CONVERT(time(0),'17:00:00'),'OUT'),
                (100,CONVERT(date,'20200901'),CONVERT(time(0),'17:10:00'),'OUT'),
                (200,CONVERT(date,'20200901'),CONVERT(time(0),'16:00:00'),'IN'),
                (200,CONVERT(date,'20200902'),CONVERT(time(0),'02:00:00'),'OUT'),
                (200,CONVERT(date,'20200902'),CONVERT(time(0),'02:15:00'),'OUT'),
                (100,CONVERT(date,'20200902'),CONVERT(time(0),'07:00:00'),'IN'),
                (100,CONVERT(date,'20200902'),CONVERT(time(0),'16:00:00'),'OUT'),
                (200,CONVERT(date,'20200902'),CONVERT(time(0),'09:55:00'),'IN'),
                (200,CONVERT(date,'20200902'),CONVERT(time(0),'10:00:00'),'IN'),
                (200,CONVERT(date,'20200902'),CONVERT(time(0),'21:00:00'),'OUT'))V(CardID,[Date],[Time],TransactionCode)),
Changes AS(
    SELECT CardID,
           DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00:00',[time]),CONVERT(datetime2(0),[date])) AS Dt2, --Way easier to work with later
           TransactionCode,
           CASE TransactionCode WHEN LEAD(TransactionCode) OVER (PARTITION BY CardID ORDER BY [Date],[Time]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS CodeChange
    FROM VTE V),
Groups AS(
    SELECT CardID,
           dt2,
           TransactionCode,
           ISNULL(SUM(CodeChange) OVER (PARTITION BY CardID ORDER BY dt2 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) AS Grp
    FROM Changes),
MinMax AS(
    SELECT CardID,
           TransactionCode,
           CASE TransactionCode WHEN 'IN' THEN MIN(dt2) WHEN 'Out' THEN MAX(dt2) END AS GrpDt2
    FROM Groups
    GROUP BY CardID,
             TransactionCode,
             Grp),
--And now original Logic
CTE AS(
    SELECT CardID,
           GrpDt2 AS DatetimeIn,
           LEAD([GrpDt2]) OVER (PARTITION BY CardID ORDER BY GrpDt2) AS DateTimeOut,
           TransactionCode
    FROM MinMax)
SELECT C.CardID,
       CONVERT(date,DatetimeIn) AS DateIn,
       CONVERT(time(0),DatetimeIn) AS TimeIn,
       CONVERT(date,DatetimeOut) AS DateOtt,
       CONVERT(time(0),DatetimeOut) AS TimeOut,
       DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE,DatetimeIn, DateTimeOut), CONVERT(time(0),'00:00:00')) AS Duration
FROM CTE C
WHERE TransactionCode = 'IN';
```

Comment: you forgot the group by clause in your cte

Comment: Had just noticved that myself, @SMor, whoops. Good job I go home in 10 minutes ;)

Comment: Hi, thank you... i think, for the first query the result is OK and more simple. BUT, please see on my expected result.  | 200 | 2020-09-01 | 16:00 | 2020-09-02 | 02:00 |   10:00. There is transaction OUT on the next day, so, how to get this? For using LEAD, i cannot use this because the data will always multiple record (sometime cardid will push the button IN twice).

Comment: Your sample data doesn't demonstrate that, @korong . If your sample data isn't representative, we too cannot be expected to provide representative answers.

Comment: For the sample data we have, the above does work: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aebe60307762fc8fb5c176fecb8c3153)

Comment: @Larnu i already edit the question, please see. And put the condition. And i dont think i can use LEAD for that sample data.

Comment: OK, now we have a gaps an island problem, that requires a minimal change.

Comment: That should do it then, @korong .

Comment: Thank you so much! It Works! But it should be DateTimeOut for the last line on your query...

Comment: @larnu i forgot if there is a case that one of those CardID have "IN" transaction code but doesnt have "OUT" or vice versa. Then we need to show "NULL" for that IN or OUT. is it possible?

Comment: That should already happen, @korong . But please don't change the rules after accepting an answer.

Comment: @Larnu please see my new question, hope you can help me. [new Q] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025450/select-first-in-and-last-out-time-different-date-and-null-condition-from-dat/64025901?noredirect=1#comment113224451_64025901)